# experiencing error while trying to get gateway_load_balancer_endpoint in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, terraform, firewall

I am trying to filter gateway_load_balancer_endpoint with data "aws_network_interface" and getting error.

```
data "aws_network_interface" "outbound" {
  filter {
    name   = "interface-type"
    values = ["gateway_load_balancer_endpoint"]
  }
}
 
Error: error reading EC2 Network Interface: too many results: wanted 1, got 2

   with data.aws_network_interface.outbound,
   on network-firewall.tf line 195, in data "aws_network_interface" "outbound":
  195: data "aws_network_interface" "outbound" {
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the error message - you have two network interfaces which match the `interface-type=gateway_load_balancer_endpoint` criterion. I.e. your reference is ambiguous.

What you can do is add another criterion to distinguish between these two.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. That is correct. i have two eni's  of type gateway_load_balancer_endpoint. Should the second filter be unique?

Comment: It's enough if the combination of these two are unique.